# gzip with webserver without content-coding

Tags: encoding, compression, webserver

I have a webserver without content-coding (boa and not enough ressources). is there a possibility to put ziped javascript-file on the webserver and unzip it at the browser after downloading like content-coding?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes. You would need to add the Content-Encoding: deflate header to your http response. 
You can not place a zip file created by a zip program on the server to be transferred, as it contains a header with the file structure before the deflate payload begins.

Also mind the differences between gzip and deflate. With gzip, similar is possible, too.